# Ubuntu - Win7 Dualboot Failure?

Tags: 12.04, windows

I switched back to Windows 7 for a while after installing and using Ubuntu 12.04 on a regular basis. I decided to reinstall Ubuntu using a flash drive I had used for it last time.

The flash drive I am using is a Verbatim 16GB, with a 2GB FAT16 partition I made to use install Ubuntu.

The problem occurred when I installed Ubuntu alongside Win7. After installing "successfully", I rebooted my computer without my flash drive in and was expecting to be greeted by a boot menu asking whether or not I wanted to boot in to Windows 7 or Ubuntu. Instead, I was greeted by a black screen with a blinking underscore as if it was waiting for me to provide input. I pressed a button on my keyboard and it returned something along the lines of "A bootable device was not detected -- please insert boot disk and press a key."

The system boots fine in too Ubuntu while my flash drive is plugged in a USB port.

I have tried to look to see whether my Windows partition is still intact using the GParted tool. Ubuntu can't find anything for "GParted". I went to the Software Center to try and install, but it apparently doesn't exist after I click "More Info".

I am hoping that Windows 7 is still intact, and that Ubuntu can be installed normally.

Comment: It sounds like you've set the BIOS to boot from USB. Do you have any other USB devices attached that could be confusing startup? Another possibility is that GRUB did not install correctly or your MBR were wiped (seems more common than not). You can look

Answer (score 1):

From your booted Ubuntu system, try opening a terminal (ctrl alt & T), then use the following commands to install grub to the internal drive :

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo update-grub
```

Replacing `sdX` with the actual drive, which will probably be `sda`, but use disk utility to double check if you are unsure.

When the process finishes, reboot without the USB, grub should load and give you the option to select windows or ubuntu.